# Separation of concerns in a node project

Tags: node.js

In my application, I have this userService class. Here I have created the generateAuthToken method. Is it a good idea to put this in the service? or Should I seperate from the service and include it as a util function to the util file?

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import config from 'config';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';  
import _  from 'lodash'; 

import { User } from '../models/user'; 
import { userRepository } from '../repositories/userRepository';

class UserService {
   generateAuthToken(user) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin }, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
      return token;
   }

   /**
    * Create new user
    */
   async createNewUser(userDTO) {  
      let user = await userRepository.getUserByEmail(userDTO.email);

      if (user) 
         throw new Error('Email already exists');

      user = new User(_.pick(userDTO, ['name', 'email', 'password']));
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

      userRepository.saveUser(user);

      return user;
   }

   /**
    * Login user
    */
   async loginUser(userDTO) {
      let user = await userRepository.getUserByEmail(userDTO.email);

      if (!user) 
         throw new Error('Invalid email or password');

      const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(userDTO.password, user.password);

      if (!validPassword) 
         throw new Error('Invalid email or password');

      return user;
   }

   async getCurrentUser() {

   }
}

export const userService = new UserService();
```

Comment: Classes tend to put us into a tunnel vision of forceful encapsulation that is not always necessary in languages like JS. If there are no states to be managed, then definitely have it as close to a pure function as possible.

Comment: This is a good question to ask. To make the decision, I would ask myself "am I ever going to need `generateAuthToken` outside of the `UserService` class?" I would say probably not, so it would be appropriate to include in this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is up to you! If you think you'll need it elsewhere then stick it in a library, otherwise you could just leave it where it is and refactor if the need arises.

When I first started with this stuff I used to get hung up on where stuff should go but, after looking at quite a lot of other code, I realised that there are many ways to achieve stuff in js.

Personally I try to be as straight forward as I can so that people having to maintain my code (including me) don't have to have to worry about obscurity or have a degree in particle physics to understand it.

One's concise is another's complex :)